# Third party web service not accessable from code untill I type the webservice URL on browser on same machine

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am having a strange scenario while working with thirdparty asmx web service.I have develop and WCF service which utilize third party webservice.The WCF service is consume by my ASP.net WebForm application. The asp.net  access the WCF service and it works fine and successful perform the job i.e. call the third party asmx web service. But after sometime my WFC service start giving  following error on asmx webserivce calls

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
```

This error keep continues until i access the asmx webservice from browser which shows to me that asmx service is running and accessible. Strangly after this browser call my WCF service keep working normal i.e. do not give timout error and perform the job on subscquent calls as well.

The WCF service is hosted on internet enable windows 2012 HyperV VM from where it access asmx web service.

Please suggest any solution . Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you contacted the owner of the service?   They're the ones best positioned to help you.

Comment: I am able to solve this . For those facing same issue I added the third party webservice IP in dns mapping in host machine entries from where WCF service is calling third party webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this . For those facing same issue I added the third party webservice IP in dns mapping in host machine entries from where WCF service is calling third party webservice